# how to pack js application to run as standalone app on Windows XP

Tags: javascript, exe, windows-xp

We have a js application (pure)
How to pack it to exe file to run on Windows XP?

Electron framework works from Windows 7 only.

Comment: I'm not sure it's possible for XP  (with existing tools)

Answer (score 1):

If your application is *only* javascript, you could look into JScript.NET, with some tips on getting started available on this page: [Make your javascript a Windows .exe](https://www.phpied.com/make-your-javascript-a-windows-exe/)

However, I assume that you're looking to not only run javascript, but to also have a graphic front-end provided by a browser. I don't believe JScript.NET has any functionality that handles that situation. You may be able to work out a hybrid solution, though -- create an application that starts a webserver hosting your application, and automatically open a browser pointed at it. It's not a fully packaged solution, as it requires that the user has a browser installed. However, it's relatively straightforward, and doable.

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at this?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions//xazzc41b(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN

```
WScript sample.js
CScript c:\scripts\sample.js
```

It seems to be available for XP:

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/windows-xp-in/0596009003/re207.html

You can't pack it as .exe but it can still run